# Is it coherent to treat the C programming language as a formal system?

Tags: programming, formal-systems

In mathematical logic, a **formal system** is a structure which includes, amongst other things, a set of axioms, and which is able to determine the truth or falsehood of statements with respect to those axioms.

A number of useful and counter-intuitive theorems were proved with respect to formal systems in the previous century. The Incompleteness Theorems are the most famous examples, but there are plenty of others.

I know that the connections between mathematical logic and **computer science** run very deep, but I have never been able to find a clear answer on what seems like a straightforward and important question: **Can one think of a programming language as a formal system?** Would this work for some languages but not other? In that case, what about the **C programming language**? Might it, perhaps, work only if we considered a **subset** of C or some other language?

If one could think of C or another language as a formal system, would applying well-known theorems about formal systems yield any interesting results?

### Potential Examples of Axioms and Statements in C

C, like almost all programming languages, contains **a form of arithmetic** within itself. It contains the usual axioms that one learns at school with respect to the **addition, subtraction and multiplication of integers**. (Things get a little more interesting when we move to *division* and non-integers; C does not always return the expected result when dividing integers and working with floats.)

The rules of arithmetic provide the **axioms**. As for the **statements**, C includes the `==` operator, which we can use to test whether an asserted arithmetical equality is true, e.g. this minimal C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (2+2 == 4) {
        printf("This is the expected result.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Something's gone badly wrong!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One could use a C program on the above lines to test whether each of a batch of arithmetical statements was true - or, for that matter, well-formed.

Comment: For clarity, can you give an example where some aspect of the C programming language might reasonably be construed to represent an axiom?  Then, can you give an example where some other aspect of the C programming language constitutes a *statement* that is either true or false?

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your helpful suggestion. In response, I've added a new section to the end of my question.

Comment: Good question, I had been wondering smthn similar for a long time. I think you'd get better reception on the computer science stackexchange tho

Comment: @Buraian I may try that. But I bet at least one person will tell me to go back here!

Comment: I went through your other questions. Let me suggestion you [this concise lecture series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V49i_LM8B0E&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic) by prof schuller. It is over Physics basically, but you'd be interested in the first lecture I believe. He talks about Godel's theorem near the end. Let me know if you liked it if you checked it out.

Comment: @Buraian Thank you ever so much! I'm working from home tomorrow, so I'll have a go at listening to it while typing away. Hopefully the first lecture will be a gentle enough introduction that I'll still get some work done!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151094/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)..